# Execute a jQuery function in other page, only from a specific link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure a way to execute a jQuery function in other page, only after a certain link is clicked from other page. 
The flow will be:

Page A: click on link to page B.

go to Page B

Page B: execute the function.

If I go directly to page B, no function shaw be executed. Only from that specific link from Page A.
How can that be done?

> $("uno").toggleClass("open").next().stop().slideToggle();

Comment: You can pass any query parameter when link is clicked on Page:A and check this parameter on Page:B, and only execute function on Page:B if that parameter is present.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri It may fail with bookmarking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any query parameter when link is clicked on Page:A and check this parameter on Page:B, and only execute function on Page:B if that parameter is present.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var queryParam = $.url('?search');
    if(queryParam) {
        // execute your function
    }
});
```

Comment: It didnt work..... So, should I put this function on Page A, and pass ?search as onclick="passVariable(this)" ?

Comment: You need to pass `search` query parameter from Page:A (when you click the link)  and write the code which I provided in Page:B

Answer (score 3):

You can use [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) to check if Page B is directed from Page A and if true, execute the function.